# Creating Optimized MBR for implementing R-tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, indexing

Simplest way for creating Minimum Bounding Rectangle(MBR) for R-tree is to start working by keeping horizontal length initially fixed and changing the vertical part till the required number of threshold points fall into it and if region is empty up-to maximum height then increase the horizontal length to accommodate the points and continue the process repeatedly.

Is there any other approach for creating optimized MBR tree..??